# 「もっと使おうPhoneGap／Cordova 2.0.0 - 第8回　File APIを使ったiOS/Androidアプリケーション作成［その5］」 のサンプルで、アップロードができない

Tags: ios, monaca, cordova

http://gihyo.jp/dev/serial/01/phonegap2/0008?page=2
上記のコードをもとにmonacaでiPadのアップロードアプリを作成中です。
現状は（一部抜粋）下記のとおりです、
uploadFileを実行することでgihyojp_logo2.pngをhttp://10.0.0.183/file/receive.phpに送るというものです。receive.phpは上のリンク先の内容と同一です。

```
function uploadFile(event) {
    // FileTransferオブジェクトを作成
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

    // アップロード先URIをencodeURIでエンコード
    var uri = encodeURI('http://10.0.0.183/file/receive.php');

    // FileUploadOptionsオブジェクトを作成し，送信時の情報を指定
    var uploadOptions = new FileUploadOptions();
    uploadOptions.fileKey = 'file';
    uploadOptions.fileName = 'gihyojp_logo2.png';
    var ref = window.open('http://10.0.0.183/file/receive.php', '_blank', 'location=no');

    // ファイルのアップロードを実行
    fileTransfer.upload(cordova.file.documentsDirectory+'gihyojp_logo2.png', uri, uploadSuccess, uploadFail, uploadOptions);
}

function uploadSuccess(uploadResult) {
    var result;

    // アップロード先(receive.php)から返るJSONをパース
    if ( 'Android' === device.platform ) {
        result = JSON.parse(uploadResult.response);
    } else { 
        // iOSの場合はエンコードされた文字列になるため，decodeURIでデコード
        result = JSON.parse(decodeURI(uploadResult.response));
    }
    alert(result);
    if ( 0 === result.errorCode ) {
        alert('ファイルのアップロードに成功しました\nbytesSent: ' + uploadResult.bytesSent + '\nresponseCode: ' + uploadResult.responseCode);
    } else {
        alert('ファイルのアップロードに失敗しました\n' + result.message + '\nbytesSent: ' + uploadResult.bytesSent + '\nresponseCode: ' + uploadResult.responseCode);
    }
}
```

実行結果は

```
ファイルのアップロードに失敗しました      
null        
bytesSent:2061
responseCode:200
```

となります。resultがなにもないようですが、どこに問題があるのでしょうか？

Comment: タイトルを変更しました。さらりと読んだ限りでは、`uploadResult.response` の中身を出力してみないと原因を知ることはできません。また、 ブラウザで`http://10.0.0.183/file/receive.php` にアクセスするとどうなりますか？

Comment: 200だし アップロード自体は成功しているように見えますよね…。 phpファイルの文字コードは何にしていますか？またはphpファイルの日本語をすべて半角英数字にした場合はどうでしょう？

Comment: result.errorCodeも表示させたところ「-1」ファイルがアップロードされていないとされているようです。調査します。

Answer (score -2):

検討しましたが、これはMonacaではなくPHPの設定の不具合でした。
アップロードに成功しました。